Can we use power Pivot to categorize Bill of Material in terms of explosion level
I am in the middle of an assignment and need to make an easy way to "filter" a bill of material through power pivot. Imagine the below is my dataset (simplified)
If I want to have an output where lets say I press on ".1", all the subsequent levels drop down and then I can further filter down on these. Perhaps this can be done through a slicer. Maybe besides each level, there is an object description so I know what item we are considering at each level. Is this possible?

I got until the stage of having a slicer but what generally happens is that the data ends up being categorized.
For instance, ..2 items are categorized, ...3 items are categorized, etc.

Would it be possible to insert a table for your data? If not, is using Power Query an option (to get it as table)? If you want to use Power Pivot you may need to build a data model to reflect the hierarchy of the objects. I have experimented with dependent drop-downs to get similar functionality - please let me know if you're interested.

May be, it can be a solution
Using VBA automation with the simplest interface - just double-click on any level cells to expand or collapse.

Put the code below into sheet's module:
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  Dim lr As Long, r As Long, i As Long, j As Long
  lr = [A1].CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
  r = Target.Row
  If Target.Column <> 1 Or r = 1 Or r > lr Then Exit Sub
  On Error GoTo GenErr
  i = Right(Target, 1)
  j = i + 1
  r = r + 1
  If Target.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Hidden Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' expand
    While r <= lr
      On Error GoTo GenErr
      If Right(Cells(r, 1), 1) = j Then
        Rows(r).Hidden = False
      ElseIf Right(Cells(r, 1), 1) = i Then
        GoTo ExitSub
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0
      r = r + 1
    Wend
  Else
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' collapse
    While r <= lr
      On Error GoTo GenErr
      If Right(Cells(r, 1), 1) > i Then
        Rows(r).Hidden = True
      Else
        GoTo ExitSub
      End If
      On Error Resume Next
      r = r + 1
    Wend
  End If
ExitSub:
  Cancel = True
  Exit Sub
GenErr:
  Resume ExitSub
End Sub

The explosion level can be 1 to 9 and should end with this digit (it can be just the single digit only).
Other solutions

Grouping
It seems you can use the grouping feature:


Pivot table - easy!

Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data
Then you can filter it by the explosion level:


But in reality, I have a huge list of "explosion levels" and this is part of an assignment where I have to make a display dashboard so a power pivot table is the way to go. The question is how to do this in a pivot table though :-) Any ideas?

Here's formula based suggestion using table and dependent drop-downs (not as nice as using slicers or Power Pivot, but just to give you an idea):

Caveat: modeling based on current level codes and description may not work as expected with duplicate names in the same level

Main logic is to get sub-levels based on the selected level and description

Get the rows by looking the levels that are at the same level or higher up (start_idx and end_idx and then CHOOSEROWS)


Main formulas enter as named formulas:


row_nums_for_level
=LAMBDA(cur,
    LET(
        cur_level, --TEXTBEFORE(cur, " "),
        cur_obj, TEXTAFTER(cur, " "),
        idx, SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table1)),
        num_level, --SUBSTITUTE(Table1[Level], ".", ""),
        start_idx, IFNA(
            XMATCH(1, (num_level = cur_level) * (Table1[Object description] = cur_obj)) + 1,
            1
        ),
        end_idx, IFNA(
            XMATCH(1, --((idx > start_idx) * (num_level <= cur_level))) - 1,
            ROWS(Table1)
        ),
        level_row_nums, SEQUENCE(end_idx - start_idx + 1, , start_idx),
        next_level_rows, FILTER(
            TEXT(cur_level + 1, "000 ") &
                CHOOSEROWS(Table1[Object description], level_row_nums),
            CHOOSEROWS(num_level, level_row_nums) = cur_level + 1
        ),
        level_row_nums
    )
)

list_rows_for_level
=LAMBDA(cur, CHOOSEROWS(Table1, row_nums_for_level(IF(cur <> "", cur, "0 Top"))))

list_level
=LAMBDA(cur,
    LET(
        cur_level, --TEXTBEFORE(cur, " "),
        cur_obj, TEXTAFTER(cur, " "),
        num_level, --SUBSTITUTE(Table1[Level], ".", ""),
        level_row_nums, row_nums_for_level(cur),
        FILTER(
            TEXT(cur_level + 1, "000 ") &
                CHOOSEROWS(Table1[Object description], level_row_nums),
            CHOOSEROWS(num_level, level_row_nums) = cur_level + 1
        )
    )
)

Defined names in Name Manager:



Name
Refers to




_01_choices (helper columns for dependent drop-downs)
=Sheet1!$H$4


_02_choices
=Sheet1!$I$4


_03_choices
=Sheet1!$J$4


_04_choices
=Sheet1!$K$4


list_level
Please see above


list_rows_for_level
Please see above


row_nums_for_level
Please see above


sel_01 (for dependent drop-drowns)
=Sheet1!$D$2


sel_02
=Sheet1!$E$2


sel_03
=Sheet1!$F$2



And get the filtered results (D5 in the example):
=LET(cur_level, IFS(sel_03 <> "", sel_03, sel_02 <> "", sel_02, sel_01 <> "", sel_01, TRUE, ""), list_rows_for_level(cur_level))



Selections with Data Validation
_01_choices#, _02_choices#, _03_choices#
# is for dynamic range
These columns can be hidden or in hidden sheet


Again, this just a quick suggestion to give you an idea. Pardon the long post.
